# "The bastard spawn of Spoo and Vox raised by RSS"

Tags: meaning

> Does a person who doesn't sweat really exist?
>
> Yes. The bastard spawn of Spoo and Vox raised by RSS.

What is the meaning of the reply? What do "bastard spawn" and "Spoo and Vox" and "RSS" mean actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SpooPoker**, **voxsartoria**, and **RSS** are all prominent members held in high esteem by members of [styleforum](http://www.styleforum.net/). Therefore, the idea that their spawn would not sweat is something of an in joke, and has nothing to do with English language usage in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

*"bastard spawn"* - means the illegitimate offspring of a couple.  In this context it is used to mean *unholy* or unpleasant in some way.

As to the meaning of **Spoo**, **Vox** and **RSS** they are names for things or people, or given that [RSS is perhaps the feed protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS), possibly bits of software.

If you give details of the context, I may be able to fill in further as to what exactly they are implying.

If this [styleforum thread](http://www.styleforum.net/showthread.php?p=4162621) is the context, I am still none the wiser, unless they are brands of sneaker, given the discussion.

Comment: @Orbling: Thanks! For the context, you can read this thread http://www.styleforum.net/showthread.php?p=4162621 . It is not long.

Comment: @Tim: Was just editing my post, as I found that link myself.

Comment: Vox is a blogging platform (among many other things) so RSS as the syndication feed protocol makes sense. I've never heard of Spoo in that context (it does have a sci-fi meaning in the context of Babylon 5, but that makes less sense than drive-by artists in forums usually make), but it's likely an obscure and hopelessly complex content management system -- that would fit the posting, even if it makes zero sense as a response in the thread.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: Yes, I had all those from some quick googling.  But wasn't sure they all were coherent.  I though the Vox platform went with RSS, but Spoo is too remote.  I love J. Michael Straczynski, and it is one of his odd devices, originally from She-Ra or He-Man, a type of food, made out of a worm thing called Spoo.  They eat it in Babylon 5 too, he thought the old reference would be amusing, I still think it's nasty!

Comment: @Stan: Thanks! Maybe Spoo is a typo for Spoon? I googled Spoo and Vox, but was suggested to search with Spoon and Vox instead. Put together, what does the original sentence try to say actually?

Comment: @Tim: I think you are trying to read most of what they said on that forum far too literally.  They are generally mocking the question.= you asked.  As the forum is about style, rather than health (?) advice.

Comment: The reason that suggestion came up is because "vox" is a common abbreviation of "vocals" on recording credits, and there are is an indie record label called "Spoon", dozens of singers with the last name "Spoon", and a seemingly endless parade of bands with the word "spoon" in their name.

Comment: A quick search on that forum reveals that Vox and Spoo(poker) are regular members.